# ionic2 file upload with extra data

Tags: cordova, angular, file-upload, ionic-framework, ionic2

In the following code the `fileTransfer.upload()` method uploads file to a remote server. But how can we send extra data like who is uploading like sending user id as well.

```
public uploadImage() {
  // Destination URL
  var url = "http://yoururl/upload.php";

  // File for Upload
  var targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.lastImage);

  // File name only
  var filename = this.lastImage;

  var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    params : {'fileName': filename}
  };

  const fileTransfer = new Transfer();

  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Uploading...',
  });
  this.loading.present();

  // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
  fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded.');
  }, err => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include such data in `params` property of `options`

```
var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    params : {
      'fileName': filename,
      'user_id': userId
    }
  };
```

The `user_id` will be received as `POST` just like `filename`.

Comment: I am passing the associative array in params and it's not accessible, so how can we pass the associative array?